# ItemsControl OverridesDefaultStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a Control `HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem`. It has set a `DefaultStyleKey` in it's `Constructor`; `DefaultStyleKey = typeof(HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem);`. When I do not set the Property `OverridesDefaultStyle`, I get the following error "`itemTemplate and ItemTemplateSelector are ignored for items already of the ItemsControl's container type;`". But when I override it's Style, it is not working. If i set a new Style, then everything works. Where is my mistake and how can I override the `Style`?

#### Style not working

```
<Style TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
                <Grid Margin="10,10,10,0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CategoryItems}" OverridesDefaultStyle="True">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Controls:FooControl Text="test" Foreground="Yellow"></Controls:FooControl>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

#### Style working

```
 <Style x:Key="HtNavigationMenuCategoryItemSingle" TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
                    <Controls:FooControl Text="test" Foreground="Yellow"></Controls:FooControl>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>



 <Style TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
                    <Grid Margin="10,10,10,0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CategoryItems}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource HtNavigationMenuCategoryItemSingle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

#### Preview of the using

[image: preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to provide a default default style for your custom WPF control you should define a `static` constructor that calls the `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata` method:

```
public class HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem : ItemsControl
{
    static HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem)));
    }

    public List<string> CategoryItems => new List<string> { "a", "b", "c" };
}
```

...and define the default style in a `ResourceDictionary` called `Generic.xaml` in a folder called `Themes` at the root of the project in which the custom control class is defined:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:Navigation="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3">

    <Style TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
                    <Grid Margin="10,10,10,0">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Yellow">
                            <TextBlock>...</TextBlock>
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CategoryItems}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

This works as far as the `Style` and `ControlTemplate` are involved.

> Actually I have the "Style working" solution with a second separate Style called "HtNavigationMenuCategoryItemSingle". But I want to know if it is possible or HOW I can override this Style in the ItemsControl like I was trying in the "Style not working" solution ...

I guess you could just define the `ItemContainerStyle` inline:

```
<Style TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
                <Grid Margin="10,10,10,0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CategoryItems}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Navigation:HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem">
                                                <Controls:FooControl Text="test" Foreground="Yellow"></TextBlock>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I want to know how to override the `Style` in my `ItemsControl` and not the default Style. The `HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem` has got a `ObservableCollection<HtNavigationMenuCategoryItem>, so the classes are Interleaved into each other. And the second level should have a "custom" Style defined in the ItemsControl and not public in the ResourceDictionary.

Comment: So you have a collection of controls to display in an ItemsControl? This is probably the wrong way of doing whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I have added a preview of my usage. A category can have direct links to sites or can have other categories with direct links inside (two seperate collections). Both (categories and direct links) should be shown on same way (same style). Categories have only these arrows (that there is a submenu) on right side.

Comment: How to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Actually I have the "Style working" solution with a second separate `Style` called "HtNavigationMenuCategoryItemSingle". But I want to know if it is possible or HOW I can override this `Style` in the `ItemsControl` like I was trying in the "Style not working" solution..

Comment: Do you want to declare the ItemContainerStyle inline or what? By the way, you should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes! That I get a separate Style for only this one situation.

Comment: Well, see my edit for an example of how to define the ItemContainerStyle inline then.